# Why are my edits and presence anonymous in Google document when I'm signed in?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-account, google-drive-sharing

I edited a Google spreadsheet document, while logged with my Google account. After looking into revision history, I could see that the revision is not under my name but under "All anonymous users".

I also tried to open the document in another window. I could see "Anonymous Kangaroo" in the list of active users instead of my own name. When I open the chat while logged in, it also shows anonymous animal name:

[image: screen shot]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's probably because you weren't invited individually to the file:

> If you share your file with a link, you may not see the names of
>   people who view it.
>
> - People you didn’t invite individually will show as anonymous when they’re in the file.
> - People you invite individually will show by name when they’re in the file.
>
> You can only see other people’s names when you give them individual permission to view a file or if they are part of a mailing list.

From: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494888?hl=en

Comment: This behavior is actually a *good* thing to avoid leaking your Google name to the person who gave you the spreadsheet link.

Comment: This behaviour is actually a _bad_ thing as you can't see who is doing what, or who is logged in. (There should be a "show who I am" button...)

Answer (score 1):

As of December 2022 - if you were anonymously added to a document and have access to edit it you can directly invite yourself.

Click the "Share" button and add your email address with "Edit" permissions. After you click "Send", the document access will be updated, and edits you make from that time forward will show as being made by your account.